# Strange SSHD connections

Tags: networking, ssh, connection

I have strange  SSHD connection from `116.31.116.41:55439` its China telecom,  do some know how to block it?

```
sshd    16016   root    3u  IPv4 4649469      0t0  TCP 104.XX.XX.XX:ssh->116.31.116.41:55439 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    16017   sshd    3u  IPv4 4649469      0t0  TCP 104.XX.XX.XX:ssh->116.31.116.41:55439 (ESTABLISHED)


inetnum:    116.16.0.0 - 116.31.255.255
netname:    CHINANET-GD
descr:  CHINANET Guangdong province network
descr:  China Telecom
descr:  No.31,jingrong street
```

Comment: sshd    16041   root    3u  IPv4 4650061      0t0  TCP 104.:ssh->116.31.116.41:63198 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    16042   sshd    3u  IPv4 4650061      0t0  TCP 104.:ssh->116.31.116.41:63198 (ESTABLISHED)

Comment: Also tcp        0      0 0:ssh      61.177.172.66:64532     ESTABLISHED

Comment: Do you have a firewall installed?

Comment: no  i don't have it

Comment: Some clarification. You have server and you wish `sshd` to be accessible for all except from specific `ip's` or you wish to secure your `server/pc` and do not allow `ssh` from internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple enable `UFW`. More about `UFW` you can find [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)

```
sudo ufw enable
```

When enable `ufw` without any `allow` rule everithing is `deny`.

Complete command for rule in `ufw` is

```
sudo ufw [--dry-run] [delete] [insert NUM]  allow|deny|reject|limit  [in|out on INTERFACE] [log|log-all] [proto protocol] [from ADDRESS [port PORT]][to ADDRESS [port PORT]]
```

Based on this rule template you can allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx on port 22 with this rule

for specific host

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to any port 22
```

if you wont to allow any to access your web server

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from any to any port 80
```

if you wish to allow access from specific network

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/yy to any port 80
```

where

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - represent network ip

yy - represent network mask

If you have `DNS`service on server use make rule for `port 53` and `proto tcp` and `proto udp`.

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/yy to any port 53
sudo ufw allow proto udp from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/yy to any port 53
```

Comment: I made  grep sshd /var/log/auth.log
and  exit is  Received disconnect from 61.177.172.66 port 39445:11:  [preauth]
Aug  8 06:29:58  sshd[19131]: Disconnected from 61.177.172.66 port 39445 [preauth]

Comment: I made rule family="ipv4" source address="116.31.116.0/26" reject

rule family="ipv4" source address="61.177.172.0/26" reject

Comment: for the moments is ok, Thanks, guys  you are the best ;)

Comment: @KamilHadzyjew please accept the answer :)